# Replace a word in a sentence with an input field

Tags: javascript

For example, replace the word "Europe" in "I want to go to Europe" with a text field.
My following attempt doesn't work.

```
let sentence = "I want to go to Europe"
let i = `<input type="text" size="6">`
let s = sentence.replace(/Europe/,i)
```

In the browser, it displays `<input type="text" size="6">` instead of the desired input field.

Comment: You don't show us how the variable `s` is being used, but you're probably setting the text of the element rather than the HTML of the element. Using `innerHTML` to set the HTML of the element to `s`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Hello, @AndyRay, but I don't want to replace the entire innerHTML with the input field. I just need the input field to replace that word "Europe".

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.innerHTML` instead `.innerText`. This is the comparison :

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById("sentence1");
let div2 = document.getElementById("sentence2");
let sentence = "I want to go to Europe"
let i = `<input type="text" size="6">`;
let s = sentence.replace(/Europe/,i);
div1.innerHTML = s;
div2.innerText = s;
```

```html
<div id="sentence1"></div>
<div id="sentence2"></div>
```

---

To replace a word in a sentence with an input field, you can try this:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("country");
let button = document.getElementById("replace");
let div = document.getElementById("sentence");
let sentence = "I want to go to Europe";
div.innerHTML = sentence;
//let i = `<input type="text" size="6">`;
button.onclick = function() {
  sentence = div.innerHTML;
  let s = sentence.replace(sentence.split(" ").at(-1),input.value);
  div.innerHTML = s;
}
```

```html
<input id="country" type="text" />
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
<div id="sentence"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear. I assume you're trying to do the following:

```js
let sentence = "I want to go to Europe";
let i = `<input type="text" size="6">`;
let s = sentence.replace(/Europe/,i);

document.getElementById('sentence-wrapper').innerHTML = s;
```

```html
<div id="sentence-wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<input type="text" size="6" id='text'>
<p id="inpVal"></p>

</body>
<script>
let inpVal = document.getElementById('text')

inpVal.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
    let sentence = `I want to go to ${e.target.value}`

    document.body.querySelector('#inpVal').innerHTML  =  sentence
})


</script>
</html>
```